# Before 1 CE/AD Algorithms make calendar calculations tricky

Tags: php, date, julian-date

I did some more research the following is the output for the respective algorithms:

JD 1099114.5

PHP: 3 Mar 1704 B.C.E. 12:00:00 (PHP Internal convertor)
FLN: 0 Mar 1703 B.C.E. 12:00:00 (Fliegel-Van Flandern)
MEU: 18 Mar 1703 B.C.E 12:00:00 (Jean Meeus "Astronomical Algorithms, 2nd ed., corrected)
RICH: 4 Mar 1703 B.C.E. 12:00:00 (Richards in Explanatory Supplement 3rd Ed.)

Each Algorithm has its issues and quirks about starting times etc.

Meeus assumes that there is a Gregorian year 0 (between -1 and 1), even if this is astronomically correct, it makes little sense from a calendrical perspective.  Technically then all the results to convert into Gregorian dates is just wrong?

Comment: Thank you for that, is there a way to correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful reference is http://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/docs/c15_usb_online.pdf, by E. G. Richards, Chapter 15 of the *Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac* 3rd ed., University Science Books, 2013. On page 591 it is explained the currently used notation of negative years for years before AD 1 was introduced by Jacques Cassini in 1740, and there **is** a year 0 between the years 1 and -1. On page 592 it is stated that the Julian Day Number of Tuesday -4712 January 1 (Julian calendar) is 1. Experimentation will show this can only be if astronomical year numbering includes a year 0. The origin of Julian day numbers is given in the same book in the "Time" chapter by D. McCarthy & B. Guinot, as "1 January 4713 B.C." Nowhere in this book can I find any hint that there should be a difference in how years are numbered depending on whether one is using the Julian or Gregorian calendar.

The Fourmilab calendar converter https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/ is a good converter, with one quirk: it uses negative signs rather than AD/BC for year numbering, but considers the Gregorian calendar to have a year 0, and the Julian calendar to not have a year 0, which I consider to be a mistake. Correcting for this mistake, it says that the original poster's Julian date 1507900 (I assume 1507900.0 exactly) is noon -584 May 22 Gregorian, or -584 May 28 Julian calendar. These dates may be used for comparison in evaluating the correctness of various algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Meeus' Algorithm is actually in error (thank you Paul for pointing this out) there should be no 0 in Gregorian years, which means that all dates prior to Gregorian year 1 (i.e. Gyr < 0) are in error.  Post Gyr (Gyr >= 1) are correctly converted.  Also, he only has the convertor for dates post 1582G.

It seems therefore that the correct date is that listed by the jdtogregorian converter supplied by PHP.